# Как исправить значение в switch

Tags: java, android

Слова в кавычках ("apple", "bread", "cheese") подчеркнута красной волнистой линией! Как исправить?

```
public void switchButton(Button button) {
        switch (button.getText()) {
            case "apple": //слова в кавычках ("apple", "bread", "cheese") подчеркнута красной волнистой линией!!! Как исправить?
                button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
                break;
            case "bread":
                button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread));
                break;
            case "cheese":
                button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cheese));
                break;
        }
    }
```

И использовал

```
Button button1, button2, button3;
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

switchButton(button1);
switchButton(button2);
switchButton(button3);
```

Comment: @FullyRetarded но мне нужно проверить полученный текст, но не могу реализовать

Comment: А где ты тут текст получаешь? Зачем вообще нужно переименовывать кнопки, а потом получать их названия?

Comment: Есть три кнопки и на них рандомно попадется один из трех текста ("apple""bread""cheese"). Текст какой соответственно background будет таким. Например на любую кнопку попался текст apple, автоматически background будет R.drawable.apple.Смог донести?

Comment: @DeveloperChingis, во-первых, как ответил @katso, это `switch (button.getText()) {` замени на это `switch (button.getText().toString()) {`. во-вторых, вот эту строку `android.util.Log.v("", "string=" + button.getText().toString());` вставь перед `switch (button.getText().toString()) {`. Теперь открой логи и найди `string=...`, скажи, что написано.

Comment: @L'Esperanza Почему если текст с базы данных изображения не ставятся?

Comment: @DeveloperChingis, я не понимаю о чём вы говорите. Извините. Maybe english?

Answer (score 2):

`button.getText()` возвращает `CharSequence`

Вам нужно сделать так:

```
button.getText().toString()
```

Comment: как я понял, если текст с база данных взят, то не считает да?Просто думает что текст пуст

Answer (score 1):

Если подчеркивает красным, то скорее всего в JDK 1.6 или ниже используете. `String` в конструкции `switch` доступен только с java 7. Скачайте JDK 7